# cron.daily gives apt error. "not found"

Tags: apt, bash, cron

I recently upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 and after that I get these strange errors in my cron e-mail. Sadly I didn't remember what version of ubuntu I was upgrading from but I think it was the latest before 15.04.

The rsync script called by backup_nas still works, it's just a simple bash script that calls rsync.

```
/etc/cron.daily/apt:
/etc/cron.daily/apt: 91: /etc/cron.daily/apt: date: not found
/etc/cron.daily/apt: 97: /etc/cron.daily/apt: rm: not found
/etc/cron.daily/apt: 448: /etc/cron.daily/apt: pidof: not found
/etc/cron.daily/apt: 176: /etc/cron.daily/apt: date: not found
/etc/cron.daily/apt: 176: /etc/cron.daily/apt: date: not found
/etc/cron.daily/backup_nas:
sending incremental file list
```

My `/etc/crontab` :

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

My `/etc/anacrontab`:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root

# These replace cron's entries
1       5       cron.daily      run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7       10      cron.weekly     run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly        15      cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

What could be the problem? 
I have done a `apt-get dist-upgrade` and it does not give me any errors. Also I tried to reinstall unattended-upgrade but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Does your `/etc/crontab` contain an appropriate `PATH`? if in doubt, please [edit] your question to include the contents of that file as well

Comment: I have never changed anything there so I hop it's correct. Updated accordingly.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/647912/edit) and add the output of `cat /etc/anacrontab`

Comment: Sure. I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all instances of **date** with **/usr/bin/date** and do the same for every command/path.

Use absolute paths in cron scripts, expect the shell to be dumb and not use any PATH or environmental variables. Also the shell used by default is /bin/sh not bash.

> date: not found

```
which date
/usr/bin/date
```